# Map to avoid Duplicate records

Tags: triggers, salesforce

> I have a Holiday Custom object,it contains Unique Dates based on
>   country based How to retrieve the value in Map

I have tried:

```
 List<Holiday__c> holidays = new List<Holiday__c>([Select id, Date__c,Country__c from Holiday__c]);

    Map<date, Holiday__c> mapOfHolidays = new Map<date, Holiday__c>(); 
    for (Holiday__c holiday: holidays)  mapOfHolidays.put(holiday.Date__c , holiday);
```

Suppose date for example 3/8/17 is for country france and Italy,If i put Key Value as Date__c,Map does not contain Key as duplicates,But for each country unique Dates are there

**So what i have to use Key and Value in Map,I want to retrieve the date using Map,please anyone Help for me the answer**

```
trigger ignoreweekends on order (before insert,before update) {

    Set<id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (order ord : Trigger.new) {
        accountids.add(ord.AccountId);
    }

    map<id, account> mapOfAccounts = new map<id, account>([select id,JDE_Date_Delivery_Offset__c from account where id IN: accountIds]);

    List<Holiday__c> holidays = new List<Holiday__c>([Select id, Date__c from Holiday__c]);

    Map<date, Holiday__c> mapOfHolidays = new Map<date, Holiday__c>(); 
    for (Holiday__c holiday: holidays)  mapOfHolidays.put(holiday.Date__c , holiday); 

    for (order so : Trigger.new) {
        Account acc = mapOfAccounts.get(so.AccountId); 
        for(integer i=0;i<=acc.JDE_Date_Delivery_Offset__c;i++) {
            Datetime dt = DateTime.newInstance(Date.today() +acc.JDE_Date_Delivery_Offset__c.longvalue(), Time.newInstance(0, 0, 0, 0));
            String dayOfWeek=dt.format('EEEE');

            if(dayOfWeek == 'saturday' || dayOfWeek == 'sunday'|| mapOfHolidays.containskey(mapOfHolidays.Date__c))  

            acc.JDE_Date_Delivery_Offset__c = acc.JDE_Date_Delivery_Offset__c+ 1;

            so.JDE_Synchronization_Date__c = Date.today().addDays(acc.JDE_Date_Delivery_Offset__c.intValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, for one unique date you have multiple countries.
For this you can create a map of Date as key and List as value instead of creating a Map of Date and Holiday_c.
For example :

```
Map<Date, List<Holiday__c>> mapofHolidays = new HashMap<Date, List<Holiday__c>>();
```

After that you can retrieve all countries for a unique date and do the required processing.

Comment: How to retrieve the Date using country based@arpit garg

Comment: in that case, iterate over List of Holiday_c objects and for each element in list, get the country and put country as key and list of dates as value.

Comment: can you please suggest do some modifications in my code according to my requirement

Comment: Country__c is as field on Holiday object

Comment: @SFDC in your code, I don't see any dependency of Country_C field.Please tell me what is the country use in your code as I see you'r just checking current date is available in map or not.

Comment: I dont Know how to get the country field using trigger code,My in that holidayobject it should not contain holiday dates

Comment: @SFDC `Map<Date, List<Holiday__c>> mapofHolidays = new HashMap<Date, List<Holiday__c>>();

for (Holiday__c holiday: holidays){


 if(! mapOfHolidays.containsKey(holiday.Date__c)){
   List<Holiday__c> listholi  = new ArrayList<Holiday__c>();
   listholi.add(holiday);
   mapOFHolidays.put(holiday.Date__c,listholi);
 }else{
  List<Holiday__c> listholi = mapOfHolidays.get(holiday.Date__c);
  listholi.add(holiday);
 }
}`   Then you can check like this :
    `if(dayOfWeek == 'saturday' || dayOfWeek == 'sunday'|| mapOfHolidays.containskey(dayOfWeek))`

Comment: what i have to give this line   if(dayOfWeek == 'saturday' || dayOfWeek == 'sunday'|| mapOfHolidays.containskey(mapOfHolidays.Date__c)), mapOfHolidays.containskey(mapOfHolidays.Date__c)) this place

Comment: @SFDC.. chk my previous comment `if(dayOfWeek == 'saturday' || dayOfWeek == 'sunday'|| mapOfHolidays.containskey(dayOfWeek)) ` ..you want to check dayOFweek is in map or not. right?

Comment: ok can you wait for a moment I can check the code it is working or not? please upvote my question

Comment: Incompatible key type String for Map<Date,List<Holiday__c>>   if(dayOfWeek == 'saturday' || dayOfWeek == 'sunday'|| mapOfHolidays.containskey(dayOfWeek)) @arpit garg

Comment: Ok..create a map like `Map<String, List<Holiday__c>> mapofHolidays = new HashMap<String, List<Holiday__c>>();` and at the time of populating key values in map, convert date into string in required format.

Comment: I am not able to get it @arpit garg

Comment: i have signed up stackoverflow today only..so my reputation is low to vote as of now..you can upvote my answer to increase :-)

Comment: `Map<String, List<Holiday__c>> mapofHolidays = new HashMap<String, List<Holiday__c>>();
for (Holiday__c holiday: holidays){
String date = DateTime.newInstance(holiday.Date__c).format('YYYY-MM-DD'); if(! mapOfHolidays.containsKey(date)){
List<Holiday__c> listholi  = new ArrayList<Holiday__c>();
  listholi.add(holiday);
   mapOFHolidays.put(date,listholi);}else{
  List<Holiday__c> listholi = mapOfHolidays.get(date);
  listholi.add(holiday);
 }
}` `String dayToCheck = dt.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
 if(dayOfWeek == 'saturday' || dayOfWeek == 'sunday'|| mapOfHolidays.containskey(dayToCheck)) `

Comment: Error: Compile Error: line 11:81 no viable alternative at character '‌' at line 11  Now String date = DateTime.newInstance(holiday.Date__c).format('YYYY-MM-DD');  this line @arpit garg

Comment: You just need to format holiday.Date_C to String in (YYYY-MM-DD) format. Can you do that with your DateTime or use any other formatter to convert date into string

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137641/discussion-between-sfdc-and-arpit-garg).